# sci-kit learn: Identifying the corresponding feature-id values when using SelectKBest

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am using sci-kit learn (version 0.11 with Python version 2.7.3) to select the top K features from a binary classification dataset in svmlight format.

I am trying to identify the feature-id values of the selected features. I assumed this would be quite simple - and may well be!
(By feature-id, I mean the number before the feature value as described [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html#datasets-in-svmlight-libsvm-format))

The following code illustrates exactly how I have been trying to do this:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest

svmlight_format_train_file = 'contrived_svmlight_train_file.txt' #I present the contents of this file below

X_train_data, Y_train_data = load_svmlight_file(svmlight_format_train_file)

featureSelector = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2,k=2)

featureSelector.fit(X_train_data,Y_train_data)

assumed_to_be_the_feature_ids_of_the_top_k_features = list(featureSelector.get_support(indices=True)) #indices=False just gives me a list of True,False etc...

print assumed_to_be_the_feature_ids_of_the_top_k_features #this gives: [0, 2]
```

Clearly, `assumed_to_be_the_feature_ids_of_the_top_k_features`  cannot correspond to the feature-id values - since (see below) the feature-id values in my input file start from 1.

Now, I suspect that `assumed_to_be_the_feature_ids_of_the_top_k_features` may, in fact, correspond to the list indices of the feature-id values sorted in order of increasing value. In my case,  index 0 would correspond to `feature-id=1` etc. - such that the code is telling me that `feature-id=1` and `feature-id=3` were selected.

I'd be grateful if someone could either confirm or deny this, however.

Thanks in advance.

Contents of **contrived_svmlight_train_file.txt**:

```
1 1:1.000000 2:1.000000 4:1.000000 6:1.000000#mA
1 1:1.000000 2:1.000000#mB
0 5:1.000000#mC
1 1:1.000000 2:1.000000#mD
0 3:1.000000 4:1.000000#mE
0 3:1.000000#mF
0 2:1.000000 4:1.000000 5:1.000000 6:1.000000#mG
0 2:1.000000#mH
```

P.S. Apologies for not formatting correctly (first time here); I hope this is legible and comprehensible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Clearly, `assumed_to_be_the_feature_ids_of_the_top_k_features` cannot correspond to the feature-id values - since (see below) the feature-id values in my input file start from 1.

Actually, they are. The SVMlight format loader will detect that your input file has one-based indices and will subtract one from every index so as not to waste a column. If that's not what you want, then pass `zero_based=True` to `load_svmlight_file` to pretend that it's actually zero-based and insert an extra column; see [its documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file.html#sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file) for details.

Comment: That's great; so my assumption has been confirmed. For simplicity, I think I'll just add 1 to each of the values in assumed_to_be_the_feature_ids_of_the_top_k_features. Thanks for such a speedy response. (BTW I read the documentation you pointed to before, but am afraid I misunderstood its implications.)

Comment: @user1735732: I admit it wasn't very clear. I pushed a patch to the dev version, so the next release will have better docs. Thank you!